# Help needed in php contact script with file attachment

Tags: php, mysql, contact-form

i have downloaded a contact script(with file attachment) from net.i am running it in wamp(pc) but when i click submit it shows this error.can you help me with this error

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\contact.php on line 38
Call S

and can you please tell me that whether the below script will work or not if not can you suggest a good contact form with file attachment

```
  <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

  <label for="name">Name:</label><br/>
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br/>

  <label for="email">Email address:</label><br/>
     <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br/>

    <label for="topic">Subject:</label><br/>
   <input type="text" id="topic" name="topic" /><br/>
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
  <label>Upload a Menu:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" size="20"><br>


  <label for="comments">Your comments:</label><br/>
  <textarea id="comments" name="comments" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br/>

   <button name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>

  </form>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
    // Pick up the form data and assign it to variables
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $topic = $_POST['topic'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    // Build the email (replace the address in the $to section with your own)
     $to = 'my@email.com';
     $subject = "Contact: $topic";
     $message = "$name said: $comments";
     $headers = "From: $email";

    // Send the mail using PHPs mail() function
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

  // Redirect
   echo('<br> your mail has been send<br>');
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: What platform are you using? Are you on localhost or a web server? Have you changed your php.ini file to mail function?

Comment: i am using local host no i dont know how to change php.ini

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the code and switching to a different script won't help.

The problem is that there is no mail server running on your computer with which to send mail.

Comment: hello dan can you help me.i have uploaded my website in net and i added my contact form to it.when i tried a demo using this contact form script, except file attachment all other things are working .can you help me

Answer (score 1):

As Dan Grossman mentioned that your code is fine, and the error you are getting is SMTP settings.
I will try to explain how you can correct these settings and set up your localhost to use your gmail (or any other external SMTP server) for sending emails.

First you need to find the php.ini file and set the sendmail_path, something like:

```
sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

Find `sendmail.ini` in "Sendmail" Folder in your WAMP installation, and add following:

```
smtp_server=localhost
smtp_port=25
default_domain=gmail.com
auth_username=[yourgmailname]@gmail.com
auth_password=[yourgmailpassword]
```

Restart your server. Now it should be able to send email.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem lies with the mailing function, not with the submission of the form.

Get help in changing your php.ini